# Выбрать записи не содержащие теги ( sql )

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Есть 3 таблицы:
посты ( post )
теги ( tag )
связь тегов и постов ( post_tag )

Стандартная таблица связей

```
post_id | tag_id
      1 | 4
      1 | 6
      2 | 5
      3 | 6
      4 | 5
      4 | 7
      6 | 8
      7 | 8
```

Необходимо получить все посты у которых нет тегов 4 и 5 ( и дополнительным условием является исключение уже просмотренных постов, допустим посмотрел посты с ид 6 и 7 )

Делаю запросом:

```
SELECT  post_id 
FROM post_tag
WHERE post_id NOT IN ( 
SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM post_tag WHERE tag_id IN (4,5) 
) AND post_id NOT IN (6,7)
```

```
mysql> explain SELECT DISTINCT `idVideo` FROM `video_tag` WHERE `idVideo` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT idVideo FROM video_tag WHERE idTag IN (263,469,478,482,537,904,967)) AND (`idVideo`<>239529) AND (`quality`=100);
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                        | key                        | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | video_tag | index | PRIMARY,video_tag-idVideo-video-id,video_tag-idVideo-idTag,video_tag-idVideo-idTag-quality,video_tag-idTag-idVideo-quality,video_tag-idTag-idVideo,video_tag-idTag,video_tag-idVideo | video_tag-idVideo-video-id | 4       | NULL | 4629680 | Using where              |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | video_tag | range | PRIMARY,video_tag-idVideo-video-id,video_tag-idVideo-idTag,video_tag-idVideo-idTag-quality,video_tag-idTag-idVideo-quality,video_tag-idTag-idVideo,video_tag-idTag,video_tag-idVideo | PRIMARY                    | 4       | NULL |  372807 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Количество индексов для теста.

Запрос отрабатывает ужасно медленно. Как бы ускорить это дело?

Comment: Во первых определитесь что у вас mysql или postgress и поправьте теги у вопроса. Во вторых приведите в тексте вопроса получающийся план выполнения (для mySQL получается с помощью `explain ваш-запрос`, для postgress как то так же)

Comment: Скорее всего будет иметь смысл заменить условие `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` на `NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)`,

Comment: или на left join с проверкой на NULL в части where

Comment: Конкретно использую Mysql, но перехать на Postgre не проблема. В Postgre есть WITH, возможно он частично поможет.

Comment: текущий план выполнения все таки покажите, по нему хоть что то видно будет.

Comment: Попробуйте в начале запроса выбирать из post, а не post_tag, там же записей меньше

Comment: добавлен план выполнения может скайп с фиксацией результата тут?

Comment: если выбирать из post,  то нужно джойнить post_tag, ведь условие выборки идёт по тегу, т.е. всё равно будет выборка по post_tag.

Comment: Вложенный запрос отрабатывает за 0,06.

Comment: А PRIMARY индекс по каким полям ?

Comment: Составной по полям idTag,IdVideo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
SELECT post_id 
  FROM post_tag
 WHERE post_id NOT IN (6,7)
 GROUP BY post_id
 HAVING sum( tag_id IN (4,5) ) = 0
```

Или такой:

```
SELECT post.id 
  FROM post
  LEFT JOIN post_tag ON tag_id IN (4,5) and post.id=post_tag.post_id
 WHERE post_tag.post_id IS NULL and post.id NOT IN (6,7)
```

Comment: Запрос выполнялся 20 сек.
    mysql> explain SELECT DISTINCT idVideo FROM video_tag WHERE (`idVideo`<>239529) AND (`quality`=100) GROUP BY idVideo HAVING sum(idTag IN (263,469,478,482,537,904,967)) = 0 ;

   select_type | table     | type                                                                                                                                                                       | key                        | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
 
    SIMPLE      | video_tag | index | video_tag-idVideo-video-id | 4       | NULL | 4629680 | Using where

Comment: @OlalaXd А ваш изначальный сколько ?

Comment: 19-22 секунды.
Есть подозрение что это из-за большого объёма передаваемой инфы

Comment: @OlalaXd Пробуйте второй, мне кажется хоть немного быстрее должен быть, ибо записей с конкретным post_id в первой таблице только одна и быстрее общий список получить

Comment: @OlalaXd И он на первом моем варианте действительно пошел по индексу по полю idVideo ... чего он там искал интересно, все строки у которых idVideo<>239529 что ли ... ну это он неправ, там же в выборке почти вся таблица ... можно условие сравнения написать в виде `idVideo+0<>239529` может это заставит его просто полным сканированием таблицы (а лучше primary индекса) пойти ...

Comment: Не уверен что правильное решение, но если добавить ограничение на выборку, limit XX, то запрос выполняется за приемлемое время

Comment: @OlalaXd Вы просто пробуйте все варианты, а там видно будет. group by в принципе должен давать максимум скорости при условии, что на выходе нужны все подходящие записи, а не часть результата (т.е. без limit), но только в том случае если выборка использует индекс включающий все поля или не использует индекс вообще. А поиск 4млн записей по индексу в котором только одно из полей участвующих в запросе - это катастрофа, это в разы медленнее, чем полное чтение таблицы без индекса

Comment: Да, второй вариант показывает 1,5 сек стабильно.
Хочется ещё раз в 10 быстрее :)

Comment: @OlalaXd А просто `select id from post` сколько времени занимает ?

Comment: С выводом
452318 rows in set (0.16 sec)

mysql> select id from video limit 1;

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @OlalaXd А план выполнения для второго запроса (который 1.5 сек) какой ?